# How to remove duplicated output when `kur dump mnist.yml`?

Tags: python, deep-learning

**The problem**

When run `kur dump mnist.yml`, the output has duplicated parts: `training` is duplicated part of `train`, `testing` is for `test`, `evaluation` is for `evaluate` and etc. See example below:

```
    {
    "evaluate": {
        "data": [
            {
                "mnist": {
                    "images": {
                        "checksum": "8d422c7b0a1c1c79245a5bcf07fe86e33eeafee792b84584aec276f5a2dbc4e6",
                        "path": "~/kur",
                        "url": "http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz"
                    },
                    "labels": {
                        "checksum": "f7ae60f92e00ec6debd23a6088c31dbd2371eca3ffa0defaefb259924204aec6",
                        "path": "~/kur",
                        "url": "http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "destination": "mnist.results.pkl",
        "hooks": [
            "mnist"
        ],
        "provider": {
            "num_batches": null
        },
        "weights": "mnist.w"
    },
    "evaluation": {
        "data": [
            {
                "mnist": {
                    "images": {
                        "checksum": "8d422c7b0a1c1c79245a5bcf07fe86e33eeafee792b84584aec276f5a2dbc4e6",
                        "path": "~/kur",
                        "url": "http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz"  
...
```

So, how do we remove the duplicated parts from the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of having the duplicate section names is be more user-friendly. That way, someone can use `train` or `training` to define their training-related section, rather than thinking, "Hmm... I don't remember what the key is. Is it 'train' or 'training'? I guess I'll look in the documentation."

It *is* true that the JSON dump can be more confusing, though. On the other hand, it is also a more advanced feature. Maybe a compromise would be to hide the duplicate keys when JSON is dumped, but this could also lead to other forms of confusion (e.g., "why did Kur accept 'training' when it isn't even a valid key, nor does it appear in a `dump`?").

Comment: As for `train` vs `training`, to be strict on one rather than flexible with two is also a way of being user-friendly I guess.

Also, I tried to order the dictionary key and values for each section using OrderedDict, as they appear in kurfile. However, I was no luck on that. Will you plan to do it? It is not a big deal though, just nicer to read I guess.

Comment: Good point about differences in user-friendliness. I will not support ordering the output (beyond, maybe, alphabetically), since it can become ambiguous when using multiple Kurfiles, especially when they are included using shell globbing (`include: path/**/file*.yml`).

Comment: I see, I think it is wise to not support ordering beyond alphabetically for avoiding further complication. 

For readability concern but you probably solved it:  
1. `settings`, `loss`, `training`... these top level sections and all the sublevels as long as they are in a long dictionary, their order is following alphabet. When beginners read this `dump` json output, can we assume when we write our kurfile, the order of all these top level and sublevels are not important for executing? 
2. on the other hand, order of layers are important, so you use list rather than a long dictionary for it

Answer (score 0):

**One solution**

comment out parts of the lines like below in [`kur/kur/kurfile.py`](https://hyp.is/Z2VsiBFOEeeoVX8SP5Xrqw/nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/EmbraceLife/kur_hack/blob/master/kurfile.py):

```
builtin = {
        'settings' : ('settings', ),
        'train' : ('train',),# 'training'),
        'validate' : ('validate',),# 'validation'),
        'test' : ('test', ), #'testing'),
        'evaluate' : ('evaluate', ), #'evaluation'),
        'templates' : ('templates', ),
        'model' : ('model', ),
        'loss' : ('loss', )
    }
```

I have experimented through `kur.Kurfile.parse` and `kur.Kurfile._parse_section`, so far I don't see any side effect of doing so.